# Initiating TinyMce on jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog

A click event on `#open_dialog` triggers a jQuery UI dialog with a ajax request to `/ajax/request/url/`

I want to initiate Tinymce on a textarea that is beeing sent back from the ajax request.

With the following code I get the log message "ajax done!" every time i click `#open_dialog` (and the ajax request is done) but Tinymce is only loaded the first time the dialog is opened. How come? And how do I initiate tinymce every time the dialog is loaded?

```
$('#open_dialog').click(function() {
    $.when($.ajax("/ajax/request/url/")).done(function() {
        console.log("ajax done!");  

        tinymce.init({selector:"textarea",
            toolbar: "undo redo cut copy paste | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | table | styleselect | removeformat ",
            plugins: "paste, table",
            paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,table,tr,td,th",
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: true,
            resize: "both"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it by removing old DOM and old editors. `ee_body` below is the DOM id of the textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        mode:"none",
        toolbar: "undo redo cut copy paste | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | table | styleselect | removeformat ",
        plugins: "paste, table",
        paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2,table,tr,td,th",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: true,
        resize: "both"
    });

});

$('#open_dialog').click(function(){
    //Remove old editors and DOM-elements 
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", false, "ee_body");
    $('#ee_body').remove();

    // When ajax request to new email is done, load Tinymce 
    $.when($.ajax("/ajax/request/url/")).done(function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", true, "ee_body");   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.